# android - parse dotnet webservice every few seconds

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-asynctask

I have a dotNet webservice that runs every couple minutes to return some xml data

I built an ASyncTask class that submits the request data to the webservice and it works good to submit the data

Then the webservice extracts that data every 2 minutes to give a response

I built another ASyncTask class to access the webservice to get that response data, but when I run the ASyncTask on a timer, it will crash the app when it first re-tries, saying the task was already running

```
public class GetPaymentsResult extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String>{

MainActivity mainActivity = MainActivity.getInstance();
public String SOAP_ACTION = "https://webservice/method";
public String METHOD_NAME = "method";
public String NAMESPACE = "https://webservice/";
public String URL = "https://webservice/payments.asmx";
private SoapObject request;
private HttpTransportSE httpTransport;
private SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
public Object response = null;
public static String resultinfo;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Integer... params){
    resultinfo = null;
    request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo pi2 = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("RequestID");        
    pi.setValue(010101);
    pi.setType(Integer.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);
    pi2.setName("APIKey");
    pi2.setValue("1234-1234-1234");
    pi2.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi2);
    envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try{
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        response = envelope.getResponse();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = e.getMessage();
    }
    return response.toString();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final String result){
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    mainActivity.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(result);               
            resultinfo = result;
        }
    });
}
}
```

and I'm using a countdown timer to call this task every ten seconds or so:

```
public CountDownTimer timer(){
    CountDownTimer times = new CountDownTimer(10000, 20) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {                
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {                
            checkPaymentreturn();
        }
    }.start();
    return times;
}
```

I'm sure there is a proper way that I should be doing this, can anyone help please?

this is the error I receive:

```
**08-09 11:37:21.169 17098-17098/com.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: com.app, PID: 17098
                                                            java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:579)
                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
                                                                at com.app.ui.CitationFragment$1.onFinish(CitationFragment.java:179)
                                                                at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:127)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: what is giving that "already running" message? your app or your so-called `webservice`?

Comment: My app, its giving a fatal exception

Comment: rule#1: post the error message, all of it.

Comment: i have posted the exception

Comment: "webservice extracts that data every 2 minutes to give a response" -- so your webservice, once called, never stops? if so, then your first call never ends, and that's why you are getting this exception.

Comment: The exception posted has nothing to do with what my webservice is doing, and everything to do with the asynctask in the android app

Comment: the exception is saying that the asynctask is not ending (you cannot call it twice) and I tried to explain why that could be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was instantiating the task at the top of the class and calling the execute from that same instance each time, but if I made the task new each time I wanted to call the task, it worked like a charm